# Pomelo EFCore throws unable to cast error in .net core 3.1

Tags: linq, mariadb, .net-core-3.1, ef-core-3.1, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

Am using `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql` library(version 3.1.1.0) to connect `maria db`from `.net core 3.1`. When there are multiple records, it is throwing `"Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Int32'."` error at **mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\Core\Row.cs:line 223.** If there is single record, `firstordefault()` works fine. If there are more, `firstordefault(), first(), tolist()` gives me this error. Any help much appreciated.

Below is my startup.cs code,

````
services.AddDbContextPool<MariaDbContext>(options => options
.UseMySql("Server=localhost;Database=******;User=localuser;Password=****;", mySqlOptions => mySqlOptions
.ServerVersion(new Version(10, 4), ServerType.MariaDb)));```
````

Comment: Please post the LINQ query you are trying to execute, the generated SQL (logged by EF Core), the model classes used in the LINQ query and their model definitions (FluentAPI) if they have any.

Comment: What is the status of your question? Did you solve it or are you still looking for an answer?